# What is the equivalent Struts 2 tag for the following Struts 1 tag?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-1

I'm migrating from Struts 1 to Struts 2. I don't know what is the equivalent Struts2 tag for the following struts1 tag

```
 <logic:equal value="1234" name="custDetail" property="ackMsg">
      <% String str = valid %>
 </logic:equal>
```

The `custDetail` attribute that is set in the request should have the value 1234. if so the script variable `str` assigned 'valid' as its value. what is the equivalent JSP code using Struts2 tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Struts 1:

```
<logic:equal value="1234" name="custDetail" property="ackMsg">
    <% String str = "valid" %>
</logic:equal>
```

Struts 2 :

```
<s:if test="custDetail.ackMsg == '1234'">
    <% String str = "valid" %>
</s:if>
```

Struts 2 refactored to remove the scriptlet:

```
<s:if test="custDetail.ackMsg == '1234'">
    <s:set var="str" value="%{'valid'}"/>
</s:if>
```

, and get the `str` value later with:

```
<s:property value="%{#str}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `custDetail` attribute that is set in the request

Then you should map request from the context. OGNL searching for keys in the value stack. And it doesn't contain request attributes. You should reference `request` from the context to get access to the request attributes.

```jsp
<s:if test="#request.custDetail.ackMsg == '1234'">
    ...
</s:if>
```

you should also provide getter and setter for `ackMsg` according to the bean spec.

Answer (score -1):

struts2 action tags are more or less similar to JSTL tags. also you can use that

```
<c:if test="custDetail.ackMsg == '1234'">
    <c:set var="str" value="%{'valid'}"/>
</c:if>
```